# What is this NETFXRepair.exe in my %windir%\Microsoft.NET directory?

Tags: .net-framework

In my `%windir%\Microsoft.NET` directory I see `NETFXRepair.exe` with a lot of `NETFXRepair.xxxx.dll` files.

What are these files used for?

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? its a valid question.. with no 100% answer

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously a system file; you can tell this because it's located in the Windows directory.

More specifically, it's a component of the .NET Framework. This is rather obvious by virtue of its containing folder's name. According to [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121115712/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx), the executable and its associated DLLs are components of version 4 of the framework.

It says (and you can infer from the name) that they are

> Resource files for .NET OS upgrade repair.

More importantly, why are you messing with these files? Are they causing you a problem?

Comment: My question was out of curiosity. I was going to check whether ildasm.exe is located under %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 when I saw these files.